# Trying to convert Apex Query List to string not sure if this is correct

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex, soql

I am trying to execute a SOQL query that may return a list. If list is null I want to set default value. I am new to apex so not sure if this is correct.

Here is what I have:

```js
// SET USERNAME STRING
string username = '%'+UserInfo.getFirstName()+'%'; 
//SET DEFAULT PRODUCTid
Id ProductID = '01t46000000nPO0AAM'; 
//MAP  IDMAPPRODUCT2
Map<Id> idmapproduct2 = new Map<Id>([Select Id FROM Product2 WHERE ProductCode like '%LAB %' AND ProductCode like:username]); system.debug(idmapproduct2); 
//CHECK IF MAP IS NULL AND IF NOT SET IT TO PRODUCT ID
if(idmapproduct2 != null)
  {ProductID = idmapproduct2;}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you dont ned a Map and your use of Map is incorrect. Use a list instead.

```
List<Product2> idmapproduct2 = [Select Id FROM Product2 WHERE ProductCode like '%LAB %' AND ProductCode like:username LIMIT 1]; system.debug(idmapproduct2); 
//CHECK IF MAP IS NULL AND IF NOT SET IT TO PRODUCT ID
if(idmapproduct2.size() != 0){
   ProductID = idmapproduct2[0].Id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use below lines....

```
List<Product2> prodList = new List<Product2>([Select Id FROM Product2 WHERE ProductCode like '%LAB %' AND ProductCode like:username Limit 1]);
if(prodList.size() > 0)  ProductID = prodList[0].Id;
```